# data format between sensors and android

Tags: android, arduino

I have been involved in the software industry for many years. I started working on a project as a beginner for connecting multiple sensors and eventually with Android mobile phone. I would like to send some data between sensors and send data to an android phone.

I know that json or xml is used as a data format between distributed applications, but these days json is widely used. But sensor is a little different from an application running on a server, because memory/space/cpu is limited.

Anyway I am wondering if there is any such thing or a certain industry format that is used as a data format to be exchanged between sensors.

I am just thinking of a plain text delimited by a certain character for simplicity which will be parsed in the Android and converted to a Java object.

I'd appreciated if someone who is familiar with this area can post a link or make comment.

Answer (score 0):

If security is a concern, sending data from an arduino may not be the best implementation(they can't deal with any reasonable encryption). If security isn't a problem you could send your data as a GET request like they do on [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/ESP8266-Wifi-Temperature-Logger/?ALLSTEPS) tutorial.May not be the best way but it works.

Sample request:

```
/update?key=0000&field1=prettydata&field2=prettydata2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a little bit strange to send some data from one sensor to another. Anyway if you are going to send some sensor readings to the android phone from Arduino you have to choose data traffic appliance, i mean use of serial or tcp. In serial arduino translate all raw output directly to a serial port, using tcp arduino can send packets to a some daemon in android phone. May be this link will help a bit https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1167/tcp-communication-between-arduino-client-and-server